# how to prove that the sum of first $\ell$ positive integers modulo a power of 2 is distinct for different $\ell$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, permutations, modular-arithmetic

I came across this result while trying to prove a computer science-related result, and cannot seem to prove it, although can confirm it numerically. Define

$$
S_{\ell, k} \equiv \left( \sum_{i=1}^\ell i\right) \mod 2^k =  \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2}  \mod 2^k
$$

where $k$ is a positive integer and $\ell$ is a non-negative integer. Show that for $0 \leq n < \ell \leq 2^k-1$, $(S_{\ell,k} - S_{n,k} )\mod 2^k \neq 0$.

I'm a little short on ideas on how to start. I've considered proving by contradiction, that is, supposing $S_{\ell,k} = S_{n,k} + \beta 2^k$ for some integer $\beta$: we then have

$$
\ell(\ell+1)-n(n+1)=\beta 2^{k+1}
$$

I feel like the next step would require showing that the left-hand side cannot be evenly divided by $2^{k+1}$. However, since the largest possible value of the left-hand side is $2^k(2^k-1)$, while the smallest possible value is $2$, I'm not certain how to prove that everything in between cannot be evenly divided by $2^{k+1}$.

I've also considered proving by induction, but I don't see any easily-obtained relationship between $S_{\ell, k}$ and $S_{\ell, k+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to prove is that if $S_l=\sum_{i=1}^l$ then $S_l\not\equiv S_n\pmod{2^k}$ whenever $0\le n<l<2^k$.

As you say, $2S_l=l(l+1)$, and you want to prove that $l(l+1)\not\equiv n(n+1)\pmod{2^{k+1}}$ under your hypotheses. Consider
$$2S_n-2S_l=n(n+1)-l(l+1)=n^2-l^2+n-l=(n-l)(n+l+1).$$
Suppose this is divisible by $2^{k+1}$. The difference of the factors
$n-l$ and $n+l+1$ is $2l+1$, an odd number. So one of $n-l$ and $n+l+1$ is
odd and the other even. If $n-l$ is odd, then the $k+1$ factors of $2$ in $2^{k+1}$ must all divide $n+l+1$, that is $2^{k+1}$ divides $n+l+1$.
On the other hand if $n+l+1$ is odd then $2^{k+1}$ divides $n-l$.

We have two cases. (i) $2^{k+1}\mid (n-l)$. This is impossible, as $0<n-l<2^k$. (ii) $2^{k+1}\mid(n+l+1)$. This is impossible, as $1<n+l+1\le 2n<2^{k+1}$. So $S_n\not\equiv S_l\pmod{2^k}$.